# mean value theorem on manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I am wondering if there is a mean value theorem on every manifold. In euclidean space $R^n$ we have: if $f$ and $g$ two smooth function and $g$ is positive, then we have some point like $p$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int f g =f(p) \int g
\end{equation}
Is it true on every smooth manifold?
Thanks

Comment: Already over $\mathbf{R}^n$ for $n  >1$, one does not have (an integral form of the) mean value theorem. There is however a mean value inequality which uses the norm on $\mathbf{R}^n$. So I'd think the answer to your question is no, but I am no expert on these matters. Best,

Answer (score 4):

All you need is that $f$ is continuous and that the domain of integration is connected. Since $g>0$ we have the estimates

$$ \inf_E f \int_E g \le \int_E fg \le \sup_E f \int_E g. $$

Dividing through by $\int_E g > 0$ we get $$\inf_E f \le \frac{\int_E fg}{\int_E g} \le \sup_E f.$$ Since $f$ is continuous and $E$ is connected, the image $f(E)$ contains the interval $(\inf_E f, \sup_E f)$; so there is some $p \in E$ such that $$f(p) = \frac{\int_E fg}{\int_E g}. $$

Comment: We probably should be mentioning what is needed to define the integral of a function over a (piece of a) manifold in the first place.